# Делаю скрипт для удаления собачек из беседы для ВК, выдает ошибку object is not iterable

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Код:

```py
import time, vk, json

chat_id = ""
token = ""
session = vk.API(access_token=token)
vk_api = vk.API(session, v="5.131", lang="ru")

banned = 0

limit = "1000"
sleep = "3.1"
block_ids = []

users = vk_api.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=2000000000 + 288)

for user_info in users:
    user_id = user_info['id']

    if "deactivated" in user_info.keys() and user_info['deactivated'] == "banned":
        block_ids.append(user_id)
        print("Найдено собачек:", len(block_ids), end="\r")
        time.sleep(0.01)

print("Начинаю удаление...")
for user_id in block_ids:
    if limit > banned:
        vk_api.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id)
        banned = banned + 1
        time.sleep(sleep)
```

Ошибка:

> TypeError: 'APINamespace' object is not iterable

(чат айди и токен я заранее убрал)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Вроде сейчас более модно пользоваться библиотекой `vk_api`, а у `vk` похуже с документацией.